# Aquamacs for macOS Mojave and Catalina - error in process filter: ‘recenter’ing a window that does not display current-buffer. How can I fix this bug?

Tags: osx, aquamacs

I'm a very new Mac user and not really an Emacs user. I just use emacs to run PVS Specification and Verification System, by typing the pvs command in the terminal to start the software.

Aquamacs was working properly but suddenly it started to get stuck when running some .pvs files (not all), including some that were working normally before. I'm receiving the following message:

"error in process filter: ‘recenter’ing a window that does not display current-buffer".

The Aquamacs windows freeze, and I just can force it to ends by using the Mac tool or closing the terminal. My Mac was running macOS Mojave when the error started, but after I updated to Catalina the bug continued.

As I'm a new Mac user a beginner in Emacs, I really appreciate any help to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get this [addressed is to](http://aquamacs.org/support.shtml):

- Confirm that your bug occurs with `open -a Aquamacs --args -Q`.
- Confirm that your bug occurs with the latest release (August) and/or
  the latest nightly.
- Report bugs with the "Send Bug Report" function (Help menu) from
  within Aquamacs.
- If you are unable to use the bug reporting function, please send your bug
  report to the Aquamacs bug reports address by directly e-mailing 
  aquamacs-bugs@aquamacs.org (no subscription required).
- Include as much detail as possible. Don't be afraid of providing too much.

Additionally, I'd file the same bug report to [the Aquamacs github issue tracker](https://github.com/davidswelt/aquamacs-emacs/issues). Aquamacs is going through a transition of maintainers, so please be patient.